# Multidimensional Integral by Change of Variable

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

$$\int{\exp((x_2-x_1)^2+k_1x_1+k_2x_2)dx_1dx_2}$$

I can perform the integration of the integral above easily by changing the variable
\begin{align}
u&=x_2+x_1\\
v&=x_2-x_1
\end{align}
Of course first computing the Jacobian, and integrating over $u$ and $v$

I am wondering how you perform the change of variable for 4-dimensional integral like below:

$$\int{\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{4}((x_{i}-x_{i-1})^2+k_ix_i)\right)dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4}$$

Is it something like:
\begin{align}
x_2-x_1&=u
\\
x_2+x_1&=v
\\
x_4-x_3&=p
\\
x_4+x_3&=q
\end{align}
Should this be enough? I think one only needs 4 new variables right? Because I was thinking the integral would be easier if I could do something like:
\begin{align}
x_2-x_1&=u
\\
x_3-x_2&=v
\\
x_4-x_3&=p
\\
x_1-x_4&=q
\end{align}
Or in general, how do you perform change of variable in multi-dimensional case. Should you generally perform it by doing:

\begin{align}
u&=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+a_4x_4
\\
v&=b_1x_1+b_2x_2+b_3x_3+b_4x_4
\\
p&=c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3+c_4x_4
\\
q&=d_1x_1+d_2x_2+d_3x_3+d_4x_4
\end{align}

And what kind of change of variable does one need to perform to perform the integration of such integration easily?

Comment: I notice that in your first attempt to substitute four variables, you have $x_3-x_2=\frac12(q-p-v-u),$ which seems worse than you started with, but in your second attempt the four variables are linearly dependent: $u+v+p+q=0,$ so the substitution may not work (depending on the $k_i$). Things are easier if you have only $n-1$ differences of the form $x_i-x_j$ for $n$ variables (as you do in the first integral), rather than $n$ differences (as you have in the second integral).

Comment: If $A$ is a real, symmetric and positive definite $n\times n$ matrix, $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\exp\left(-x^T A x\right)\,d\mu = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\sqrt{\det A}}.$$

Comment: Anyway, it would be extremely useful to know the integration bounds.